# magento REST API not accessible in iphone

Tags: iphone, magento, oauth, magento-1.7

When I try to access rest API using iPhone I have passed following parameter in URL and used both methods **POST** and **GET** but it displays `Access Denied`.

```
oauth_version="1.0", 
oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",
oauth_nonce="B0dlzkfMWCAn0TJ", 
oauth_timestamp="1366280813",
oauth_consumer_key="klkjylsiozbv6vfdsqtuheqo3kmqqzv2",
oauth_token="t9pefrwylmg7webyepsqepotlhzbytkp",
oauth_signature="NeOwbCLUPbIyF9ErnHoFQOl9%2Bwo%3D"
```

I have worked with REST Client plugin available for Firefox and Chrome, REST API is work well using REST Client plugin but not accessible in iPhone.

I am generating a random value for oauth_timestamp, oauth_signature and oauth_nonce then also REST API is displaying `Access Denied`.

Please provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//here final_sign is signature generated from following procedure.

```
$nonce = substr(md5(uniqid('nonce_', true)),0,16);
$temprealm="http://magentohost/api/rest/products";
$realm=urlencode($temprealm);
$oauth_version="1.0";
$oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1";
$oauth_consumer_key="dfddfgdgdfgddf6qgygmyvw7e3";
$oauth_access_token="fdgdfgfdgdfg357gimpdnuejvcbtk51ni";
$oauth_method="GET";
$oauth_timestamp=time();
$algo="sha1";
$key="sb88hfdihyg25ipt1by559yzbj2m3861&s7uhaheu8nrx961oxg6uc3os4zgyc2tm"; //consumer secret & token secret //Both are used in generate signature
$data="oauth_consumer_key=".$oauth_consumer_key."&oauth_nonce=".$nonce."&oauth_signature_method=".$oauth_signature_method."&oauth_timestamp=".$oauth_timestamp."&oauth_token=".$oauth_access_token."&oauth_version=".$oauth_version;

$send_data=$oauth_method."&".$realm."&".urlencode($data);
$sign=hash_hmac($algo,$send_data,$key,1); // consumer key and token secrat used here
$fin_sign=base64_encode($sign);

echo $fin_sign;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand that you use a **random** value for the *signature* and the *nonce*.
The latter would be fine, but a **random signature** would lead the receiver not to trust you as a legitimate client.

So, actually, you get the response you requested (;-)). But that does not solve your problem.

You have to generate a **valid signature** for the magento system.

Comment: yes i have to generate valied signature that i agree with your answer but my problem is it still remain the "Access denied" how can i access magento REST API using AJAX please give me solution...

Comment: My gut feeling is that there is something wrong with the authentication, even though you think it is not. Does the exact same request work from a browser? You may want to write the request through NSLog to the debug console and copy it from there into your browser. I have found nasty missing commas and slashes in my REST requests that way.

Comment: yes, you are right but how to generate signature please tell me the procedure...please

Comment: Doesn't the Magento documentation tell you that? For the REST's I use I have to sign up to get a valid signature.